# Posting image with Java Android

Tags: java, android, http, post, server

I'm developing an android application, it's very simple: the user takes a picture and uploads it to a server.
I have one problem: I usually upload image to servers converting them into a base64 string but in this case the server does not accept base64 strings but wants the full image.
For instance I can upload images using curl -F datafile="@myImage.png" http://www.myUrl.com/up.php, but I can'y use curl in android so how can I upload a bitmap (the image the user takes) without converting it into a base64 string but "pretending" to use curl?

This is how I usually post something through http:

```
    public static void send(String send) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    URL url = new URL(MessageFormat.format("http://wwww.exaple.com/index.php/",""));

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput (true);

    urlConnection.connect();

    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    try {
        param.put("datafile", send);


    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("---------", "error");
    }

    Log.d("", param.toString());

    outputStream.writeChars(param.toString());
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876971/posting-a-multipart-request-with-image-in-android